# How do I specify an XForm instance outside of an `<xform:model>`/`<xform:instance>` in the same document?

Tags: xml, xsd, xforms

How do I do the equivalent of this hypothetical xform:instance attribute that connects externalinstance from the same document:

```
<mydata xmlns="mydata-namespace" 
        xmlns:xform="http://www.w3.org/2002/xforms">
    <foo xform:instance="externalinstance">
        <bar>Baz</bar>
    </foo>
    <xform:model>
        <xform:instance id="myinstance" src="externalinstance" />
    </xform:model>
    <xform:output ref="instance('myinstance')/bar"/>
</mydata>
```

The enclosing document has defined an XSD Schema that specifies that `<foo>` must be a direct child of `<mydata>`, thus adding `<xform:model>`/`<xform:instance>` would have been in violation of the enclosing document's schema.

Suppose that I cannot change the parent's schema (as well as the many applications that have been written expecting `<foo>` to be a direct child of `<mydata>`), how can I use `<foo>` as an XForm instance?

Comment: Would it be possible to move the entire `mydata` structure into the `xforms:model` (`/xforms:model/xforms:instance/mydata/foo`)? This way, `foo`keeps its direct parent `mydata`, and there's no need for an "external instance".

Answer (score 0):

XForms recommandation does not specify where xf:model should be located. But it does not consider the possibility for the model to be declared within an instance.

Is it possible for you to apply an XSLT stylesheet to generate a more conventional document for your XForms engine?

-Alain